# This в стрелочной функции axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Пытаюсь настроить глобально axios во vue.js и [вывод сообщений](http://f3oall/vue-awesome-notifications) при ошибке

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    this.$awn.success("Your custom message"); //Тут работает
    return config;
}, (error) => axios_error(error));

function axios_error(error) {
    console.log('Ошибка запроса axios');
    this.$awn.success("Your custom message"); //Тут НЕ работает
    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

Однако получаю ошибку внутри функции `axios_error()`

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$awn' of undefined

Как решить?

Comment: this нету в стрелочных функциях, это в общем то единственное их отличие от обычных, кроме синтаксиса

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр как нету? А что же происходит в строчке с комментарием "//Тут работает"?

Comment: @Igor учитывая, что эта функция передаётся как параметр, внутри обработчика `axios.interceptors.request.use` в неё могли подпихнуть this через call/apply .

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Нет, не могли. Она же стрелочная. ("Витя, они ж - сумчатые." "Каникулы строгого режима")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  ...
}, (error) => axios_error(error));
```

-- это вызов функции `axios_error` в глобальном контексте. Вам нужно:

```
  ...
}, (error) => axios_error.call(this, error));
```